# Get data based on time Mongo DB (Laravel)

Tags: laravel, mongodb, jenssegers-mongodb

```
array:4 [▼
  "_id" => ObjectId {#1108 ▶}
  "Date" => UTCDateTime {#1112 ▼
    +"milliseconds": "1591399800000"
  }
  "token" => "1013875"
  "value" => "78.65"
]
```

Hi,
The sample object is as above,
I need to get data(collection) where the Date is equal to 1591399800000(Time in milliseconds).
Db is Mongo DB,
Laravel framework.

DB::table('table_name')->where('Date','1591399800000')->first();

not giving me the required output.

Comment: I am not a Laravel expert (or even beginner) but I am willing to that `where('Date','1591399800000')`  is treating `1591399800000` as a string, not integer number of milliseconds.   You need to do something like `where('Date',' UTCDateTime(1591399800000))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done like this and getting required results:

```
$start_time = new \DateTime('-5 minutes');

$end_time=new \DateTime('-4 minutes');

DB::table('table_name') 
   ->where('Date',array('$gte' => $start_time,'$lte' => $end_time)) 
   ->first()
```